# Access Jupyter notebook without using websockets

Tags: websocket, jupyter

We need to be able to access Jupyter notebook via a limited 'reverse-proxy' like solution. Unfortunately this 'reverse proxy' blocks any websockets communication.

Does Jupyter notebook provide an option to force non-websocket communication?

Comment: Ran into a similar situation that only HTTP proxy is supported (YARN web proxy server), did you find anything useful after posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by default. Thought it would be possible to replace the websockets connections with something like socket-io, which automatically fallback to long-polling if websocket are not available.  You would need to send patches upstream to both the frontend (notebook) and the backend (notebook server). If the patches are small and relatively strait-forward it has chances of being accepted ; though, keep in mind that using long-polling will make performance way worse.

Historically the "current" notebook is the 6th prototype, and one of the reason many of the previous one did not work is because websocket were not available as a technology at the time.